# Access Property From Another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

### Issue

---

I want to be able to check a property from another View Model to see if it has values in it, if it does do something and *vise versa*.

### Code

---

So in **View Model A** (*OnDemandMainViewModel is the class name*) I have a property which holds all the items inside of a Timeline:

```
public ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> Timeline2Items
 {
   get { return _timeline2Items; }
    set
    {
        _timeline2Items = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Timeline2Items");
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<ITimeLineDataItem> _timeline2Items;
```

Then in **View Model B** (*WizardViewModel is the class name*) I want to be able run an if statement to check if that property has any items:

```
if (//CHECK FOR ITEMS)
{

}
```

How would I be able to check to see if the property has any items or not?

Comment: ViewModelA is DataContext for what? a Window?

Comment: @Pikoh Yes, both View Models are Data Contexts for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (assuming OnDemandMain is your view1 and OnDemandMainViewModel your viewmodel1:

```
OnDemandMain win=Application.Current.Windows.OfType<OnDemandMain>().FirstOrDefault();
OnDemandMainViewModel vm=(OnDemandMainViewModel)win.DataContext;
vm.Timeline2Items.Count();
```

Comment: What does the 'cm' stand for on the second line?